# while and do/while in *.java and *.class. in JetBrain IDEA

Tags: java

I`m Study Java, But I found a problem in javatutorials.

```
/* ContinueWithLabelDemo.java */
class ContinueWithLabelDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String searchMe = "Look for a substring in me";
        String substring = "sub";
        boolean foundIt = false;
        int max = searchMe.length() - substring.length();
        test:
        for (int i = 0; i <= max; i++) {
            int n = substring.length();
            int j = i;
            int k = 0;
            while (n-- != 0) {
                if (searchMe.charAt(j++) != substring.charAt(k++)) {
                    continue test;
                }
            }
            foundIt = true;
            break test;
        }
        System.out.println(foundIt ? "Found it" : "Didn't find it");
    }
}
```

When i Debuging this program, I found something wried in its class file:

```
/* ContinueWithLabelDemo.class */
class ContinueWithLabelDemo {
    ContinueWithLabelDemo() {
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String searchMe = "Look for a substring in me";
        String substring = "sub";
        boolean foundIt = false;
        int max = searchMe.length() - substring.length();
        label26:
        for(int i = 0; i <= max; ++i) {
            int n = substring.length();
            int j = i;
            int k = 0;
            do {
                if(n-- == 0) {
                    foundIt = true;
                    break label26;
                }
            } while(searchMe.charAt(j++) == substring.charAt(k++));
        }
        System.out.println(foundIt?"Found it":"Didn\'t find it");
    }
}
```

The while loop become do/while loop. So i replace code from *.class to *.java and build it again.now the do/while loop become while loop. Is there necessary exchange them every build? why Java do this?

Comment: no need to replace your code . it is class file which is generated by compiler . so don't change class file code.

Comment: Your condition will always be true at the first iteration of the loop. Though here this is just eye candy.